# Widget multiple loop . How?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, widget

so i am building my first wp theme ever. Everything is going ok until today. The problem is multiple loop inside widget i created. When i add this widget it pops out of homepage content and breaks sidebar.  I know it's the loop but cant find solution for it. Basically this widget would be separed on the left and right, where on the left would show the latest post. On the right from the same cat would have offset 1 and show 3 more posts with thumbs and below it 4 more posts with the offset 4 from the same cat.

This is the code, with which i tried and it does show up ok, but it breaks things. I did try with some reset but as i said i am newbie and could not get it to work.

Any idea or example how this should be done woule be very appreciated. Thanks

The code with the loop ( for some reason it doesnt show properly here) so i add it here

http://pastebin.com/c0s2zsRa

Basically there are 3 loops inside 3 different div's and all them wrapped inside another dive.

Thanks

Comment: At least 2  of your ul's arent closed, clean up your code its a bit messy.

Comment: Hey Jelle, yea i noticed later. I'm working in sublime text editor, and i guess when i was trying to work it out and hit undo i left one div actually which caused this problem. It works all fine now and it looks the code loop code was ok :D Thanks